# How to download Landsat 8/9 images via eodag Python package - UnsupportedProvider

Tags: python, landsat, download, usgs, eodag

I want to automate the process of downloading Landsat 8/9 images via python. What I want to download is zip files with all bands (not some bands seperately). I have checked similar questions in GIS StackExchange and after some googling I used the landsatexplore Python package. However, it was not that reliable and I decided to use Python library eodag.

I specified productType='LANDSAT_C2L2' and provider='usgs' based on the documentation of the package. I have requested access to USGS (machine to machine) and was granted.

[image]

[image]

The error I got is "UnsupportedProvider". However, this is the name of provider I can see on documentation (https://eodag.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started_guide/register.html. I have also tried without specifying the provider='usgs' and then the default provider is earth_search. For this provider, I need an account on AWS. I would not like to use AWS. Have I missed anything regarding my approach using 'usgs'? I have attached my code below.

```
import os
from eodag import EODataAccessGateway, setup_logging
from datetime import datetime

setup_logging(0)
os.environ["EODAG__USGS__AUTH__CREDENTIALS__USERNAME"] = "xxxxxxxxx"
os.environ["EODAG__USGS__AUTH__CREDENTIALS__PASSWORD"] = "xxxxxxxxx"
os.environ["EODAG__USGS__DOWNLOAD__OUTPUTS_PREFIX"] = os.path.relpath("outputs_v2")

dag = EODataAccessGateway()

search_results, total_count = dag.search(
    # productType='S2_MSI_L1C',
    productType='LANDSAT_C2L2',
    geom={'lonmin': 1, 'latmin': 43.5, 'lonmax': 2, 'latmax': 44}, # accepts WKT polygons, shapely.geometry, ...
    start='2023-01-01',
    end='2023-01-15',
    provider='usgs'
)

# Search for products
products = dag.search(search_results)
print(products)

product = search_results[0]
print(product)

product_path = product.download()
```